# Jquery mobile panels just don't work..

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, user-interface

Jquery mobile panels just don't work, Am I missing something?
I read the documentation and I just don't understand why doesn't work.

```
<div data-role="page">

  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#menu-panel" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext">Menu</a> <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="bottom" data-inline="true">Profilo</a>        
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>

    <div data-role="panel" id="menu-panel">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="match.html">Match</a></li>
            <li><a href="profilo.html">Profilo</a></li>
            <li><a href="mercatino.html">Mercatino</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /panel -->       
</div><!-- /page -->
```

This id the [JsFiddle Page](http://jsfiddle.net/NRnfX/)

I'm new with jquery mobile.. so sorry if the problem will be stupid ^^
Thank you

Comment: what exactly doesnt work?

Comment: You can see the panel after the footer.. But panel should work like this http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/panels/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your JQuery Mobile Version. Do it here: http://jquerymobile.com/download/

Answer (score 2):

You have a wrong version (1.2.1) of JQueryMobile loaded. 
Panel support is starting from JQM  1.3.0.
I forked your jsFiddle and updated the jQuery and JQM to 1.3.2 [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cardinal27513/sd5ne/7/).

The same code as yours works.

```
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#menu-panel" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="notext">Cancel</a> <h1>Home</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="bottom" data-inline="true">Profilo</a>    
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="bottom" data-inline="true">Profilo</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="bottom" data-inline="true">Profilo</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" data-iconpos="bottom" data-inline="true">Profilo</a>        
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>

    <div data-role="panel" id="menu-panel">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="match.html">Match</a></li>
            <li><a href="profilo.html">Profilo</a></li>
            <li><a href="mercatino.html">Mercatino</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /panel -->       
</div><!-- /page -->
```